# Just made a web template, what changes should I make?

Tags: website-design, templates, web

http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/668/unled3yu.jpg

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider changing the site you are asking this on ;)

[Try this site instead.](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/)

Comment: You're probably right, but shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: No it's my answer, and kind of a pun "What changes should I make? The site you are on." :) It's going to be closed shortly anyway...

Comment: Haha. You're right! :)